# Is there an in-kernel way to debug netlink protocol communications?

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, netlink

Netlink (as in, the kernel internal protocol) seems to be very difficult to debug without additional tools - which I can't actually use because I'm on a very confined embedded system.

Is there an in-kernel debugging option for netlink if I recompile from source? e.g. logs confirming messages have been received and understood

I've set debug verbosity to 15 but I can't find an option that specifically relates to netlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resorted to adding my own print logging to the kernel to get visibility on netlink - I can't see any official solution configurable for this.

`rtnetlink_rcv_msg` in `linux/net/core/rtnetlink.c` is a good place to start, and you can add `printk` calls without any extra work, e.g:

```c
printk(KERN_INFO "netlink msg recv msgtype %d\n", type);
```